# java. socket - ObjectInputStream

Tags: java

Я создаю сервер и клиента на сокете и хочу чтоб они обменивались объектами.

```
1. Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
2. InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
3. ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
4. ReadMsg readMsg = new ReadMsg(objectInputStream,eventControllerBlockingQueue);
```

И вот зависает процесс на 3й строчке, ошибок нет, просто чего то ждет...
Подскажите, чего ждет то?

Comment: Ну, как мне кажется, он пытается прочитать то, что попадает на сокет. Попробуйте прочитать [4 главу](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/654-klassih-socket-i-serversocket-ili-allo-server-tih-menja-slihshishjh). Также, я уверен, если вы закроете `inputStream` на 3 строке, то у вас `objectInputStream` выдаст или ошибку, либо пойдет дальше и на 5 строке будет ошибка.

Comment: Проблема у меня была в сервере, нужно сначала создать на нем ObjectOutputStream а потом Input... а у меня наоборот было

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ObjectInputStreamandObjectOutputStreamfromSocket.htm